# defining functions with optional arguments

Tags: python, option-type, function

Hi I'm trying to understand how to implement optional arguments in a python function. For example, in the basic function below

```
def Ham(p,*q):
    if q:
        print p+q
    else:
        print p

Ham(2)


Ham(2,3)
```

I expect Ham(2) to return '2' which it does, however Ham(2,3) gives an error.

EDIT: Many thanks. Many of your answers were useful.

Comment: Have you read the relevant sections of [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)?

Comment: also, take a look at `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular example, I think you mean to do:

```
def Ham(p,q=None):
    if q:
        print p+q
    else:
        print p
```

That is, give `q` a default value of `None` and then only calculate `p+q` if a `q` is provided. Even simpler would be:

```
def Ham(p,q=0):
    print p+q
```

Comment: This was a bad example. I was trying to make use of the optional argument.

Comment: @Imran, don't dig in yourself deeper.  `*q` doesn't do what you think it does, read the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Using *q you are specifyng a list of arguments not known until runtime and python expecting q to be a tuple, it means you can call Ham like below:

```
Ham(1, 2) # q = (2,)
Ham(1, 2, 3) # q = (2, 3)
Ham(1, 2, 3, 4) # q = (2, 3, 4)
```

Insidia of Ham function you have to treat q as a tuple, I mean, q[0] rather than q. You can have a look to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) to have a better idea.